# Minifying SVG by combining same color rect pixels

Tags: svg

I have an SVG like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg version="1.1" width="68" height="68" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <rect x="14" y="24" width="1" height="1" fill="red" />
    <rect x="14" y="24" width="1" height="1" fill="red" />
    <rect x="14" y="24" width="1" height="1" fill="red" />
    <rect x="14" y="24" width="1" height="1" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

I want to change this to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg version="1.1" width="68" height="68" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <rect x="14" y="24" width="1" height="4" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Is there an automated way to combine `Rect` of same color and replace the width and height of them?

Comment: SVG is just markup. If you want to change it then you just need to edit the file.

Comment: I understand, but if I have 10,000 lines of this - I was curious if there was an automated method. @RobertLongson

Comment: If it were me I'd write an XSLT script. Maybe you know some other XML transformation tool though. If so, use what you know.

Comment: Do you need only "same colour", or also same x, y, width and height?

Comment: If you have 10.000 lines/elements you are probably not writing the code by hand. Where does all this data come from? If it is from a database I would suggest querying the database so that all elements turn out unique. Or as @RobertLongson suggest use XSL to transform/filter the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert all `<rect>` to `<path>` elements employing Jarek Foksa's [**pathData polyfill**](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) and combine their path commands:

1. search for different fill colors
2. query all fill colors
3. convert rects to paths
4. concatenate `d` properties

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

function mergeByColors(svg) {
  let els = svg.querySelectorAll("path, rect, circle, polygon, ellipse ");

  // find colors
  let colors = [];
  let fills = [];
  els.forEach(function(el, i) {
    let fill = el.getAttribute("fill");
    fills[fill] = [];
    if (colors.indexOf(fill) == -1) {
      colors.push(fill);
    }
  });

  // loop through colors
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    let fillEls = svg.querySelectorAll('[fill="' + colors[i] + '"]');
    let pathsCombinedData = "";

    //convert primitives to paths via pathData normalizing
    fillEls.forEach(function(el, i) {
      let pathData = el.getPathData({
        normalize: true
      });
      //remove shape
      el.remove();
      //concatenate path data
      pathData.forEach(function(command, c) {
        pathsCombinedData +=
          " " + command["type"] + "" + command["values"].join(" ");
      });
    });

    // append fill group path
    let pathTmp = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "path"
    );
    pathTmp.setAttribute("fill", colors[i]);
    pathTmp.setAttribute("d", pathsCombinedData);
    svg.appendChild(pathTmp);
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em
}

path{
opacity:0.7
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.3/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <button type="button" onclick="mergeByColors(svg)">Merge rects </button>
</p>

<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 68 68" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="14" y="24" width="10" height="10" fill="red" />
    <rect x="14" y="34" width="10" height="10" fill="red" />
    <rect x="14" y="44" width="10" height="10" fill="red" />
    <rect x="14" y="54" width="10" height="10" fill="red" />
    <rect x="24" y="54" width="10" height="10" fill="red" />
    <rect x="34" y="24" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
    <rect x="34" y="34" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Now you get one `<path>` element for each fill color.
Final output:

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 68 68" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="red" d=" M14 24 L24 24 L24 34 L14 34 L14 24 Z M14 34 L24 34 L24 44 L14 44 L14 34 Z M14 44 L24 44 L24 54 L14 54 L14 44 Z M14 54 L24 54 L24 64 L14 64 L14 54 Z M24 54 L34 54 L34 64 L24 64 L24 54 Z" />
  <path fill="blue" d=" M34 24 L44 24 L44 34 L34 34 L34 24 Z M34 34 L44 34 L44 44 L34 44 L34 34 Z" />
</svg>
```